# Include issue in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, class, object, include

I have several folders:

- `localhost/mysite/inlcudes`
- `localhost/mysite/public`

... and inside includes, several files:

- `database.php`
- `config.php`

Inside `database.php`, I have created a class to handle all the connection stuff. I created a database object. I tested the connection and queries using `test.php` in the same folder. Everything works fine, but when I try to test `database.php` in `public/index.php` it tells me the variable is not set.

**Code:**

```
<?php
include ('../../includes/database.php');

if (isset($database)) {
   echo"working";
} else {
   echo "not";
}
```

**Result:**

```
not
```

Comment: Have you checked your PHP logs?

Comment: Always make sure you are using relative paths based in the current directory of the file you are working with using `__DIR__ . /relative/path/file.php`

Comment: And if you **need** a file to run your script, consider using `require` (or `require_once`) instead of `include`. That way you will get an error message if the file cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `include_once('your_path')` instead of `include('your_path')` ?

Comment: yes,Database connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Comment: finally got the solution,just need to change 
allow_url_include = On in php.ini

Comment: Yup definitely you have to put on status for allow_url_include of your php.ini because This test checks to see if allow_url_include is enabled.
 Note that this setting is only available since PHP 5.2, so the test will not run if you have an older version.By default, allow_url_include is disabled.
The setting can also be enable/disabled in apache's httpd.conf file:
# For Enable allow_url_include 
php_flag  allow_url_include  off

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your database file location is "localhost/mysite/inlcudes/database.php" and your index file location is "localhost/mysite/public/index.php" it looks like you need to go just one directory backward.

so the include function should look like this

```
include("../includes/database.php");
```

Comment: In this case include("../includes/database.php"); I am getting error:-Database connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Comment: **It's looks like the MySQL class you're using dropping this error.** If Your MySQL server is in the same machine, you should change the MySQL Host to 127.0.0.1 OR localhost.

Comment: When i am testing it with a test.php in includes folder it working fine all type of queries.

Comment: finally got the solution,just need to change allow_url_include = On in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Your include file is probably not happening correctly... You can try debugging your  "../.." path with realpath.

Start like this

```
var_dump(realpath('../'));
var_dump(realpath('../../'));
var_dump(realpath('../../includes'));
var_dump(realpath('../../includes/database.php'));
```

If one returns nothing, that means the path doesn't exists...

Comment: 1)string(24) "C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite 2)string(15) "C:\xampp\htdocs 3)bool(false) 4)bool(false)

Comment: You should activate your error while you debug this (or check your php log). The error will be outputted in the browser with this.
ini_set('display_errors','on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

You have the wrong path for your include, like mentioned above it seems the right path would be ('../includes/database.php');.

Using require would "stop" if the script isn't found and the error will be easier to fix/follow...

Comment: When i am using include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\includes\database.php'; it is working!!!!